# How to create a lag column with a constraint in data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My reproducible data is ;

```
mydf <- structure(list(product = c("4689", "4695", "513377", "604018", 
"4693", "513376", "4706", "4691", "4691", "1212", "601606", "4755", 
"502659", "4679", "9934"), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), 
    weeks = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
    15), sales = c(18L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 20L, 11L, 20L, 
    12L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 15L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to calculate mean of sales for three weeks before, and followed this way ;

```
mydf[,lookup_week := weeks - 3]

lags <- mydf[,.(lag = mean(sales)),by = weeks]

joint_table <- merge(mydf,lags,by.x = 'lookup_week',by.y = 'weeks',all.x = T)
```

and it returns ;

```
    lookup_week product year weeks sales lag
 1:          -2    4689 2018     1    18  NA
 2:          -1    4695 2018     2    13  NA
 3:           1  513377 2018     4    16  18
 4:           2  604018 2018     5    10  13
 5:           3    4693 2019     6    11  NA
 6:           4  513376 2019     7    16  16
 7:           5    4706 2019     8    20  10
 8:           5    1212 2019     8    12  10
 9:           6    4691 2019     9    11  11
10:           7    4691 2019    10    20  16
11:           8  601606 2021    11    10  16
12:           9    4755 2021    12    14  11
13:          10  502659 2021    13    14  20
14:          11    4679 2021    14    19  10
15:          12    9934 2021    15    15  14
```

Here are the issues:

For row 5, I need to check where `weeks` equals to 3. But it doesn't exist, I need to go closest week before 3. it should be 2 in this example. if it wouldn't exist as well, I had to go to where `weeks` equals to 1.

The other issue is that, there should be at most 1 year between the year of the observation that the lag came from and the year of the observation from which I calculated the lag. So if I want to restrict going back as much as possible, it should be able to go back at most one year to calculate lag.

How can I do this ?

`dplyr` solutions are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first problem, take a look at `tidyr::fill`

Comment: For the first problem, use left roll join `lags[mydf, roll=TRUE, on = c(weeks = "lookup_week")]`.  I am a little confuse for the second issue, I don't know what you want to get. Can you provide some example as data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to calculate mean of sales for three weeks before
>
> But it doesn't exist, I need to go closest week before 3. it should be 2 in this example. if it wouldn't exist as well, I had to go to where weeks equals to 1.
>
> So if I want to restrict going back as much as possible, it should be able to go back at most one year to calculate lag.

You can do:

```
mydf[, lag3 := .SD[.(weeks-3), on=.(weeks), roll=52-3, mean(x.sales), by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

which gives

```
> mydf[order(weeks)]
    product year weeks sales lag3
 1:    4689 2018     1    18   NA
 2:    4695 2018     2    13   NA
 3:  513377 2018     4    16   18
 4:  604018 2018     5    10   13
 5:    4693 2019     6    11   13
 6:  513376 2019     7    16   16
 7:    4706 2019     8    20   10
 8:    1212 2019     8    12   10
 9:    4691 2019     9    11   11
10:    4691 2019    10    20   16
11:  601606 2021    11    10   16
12:    4755 2021    12    14   11
13:  502659 2021    13    14   20
14:    4679 2021    14    19   10
15:    9934 2021    15    15   14
```

How it works:

- This is a join `x[i, ...]` of the column `i=.(weeks-3)` with `x=mydf`.
- The join condition is: use the weeks column up to 52 weeks prior.
- The aggregation for the mean uses `by=.EACHI` to group by each row of `i`.
- `x.sales` are values of `x` found in the join.
- `mean(x.sales)` is calculated as a column with name `V1`

Try running `mydf[.(weeks-3), on=.(weeks), roll=52-3, mean(x.sales), by=.EACHI]`